# How to display day of the week instead of dates at line chart in Power BI?

Tags: sql, powerbi, ssas

I want to show day of the week instead of dates in the line chart. I am using SSAS as data source. I already search online for solution, some of it suggest to use sort by column. But in the Power BI, the option is disabled, since I am using SSAS and Live connection.

Answer (score 2):

For Live Connections you will be limited to the modifications that you can do. For your use case you'll need to add a column, which you can NOT do with a live connection. You would use a DAX formula of DAY([date]) to do this. I'm assuming that you have a Calendar/Date dimension table in the SSAS model, I would recommend feeding back to the data owner to add the column and other date categories that you need.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, I use live connections and I'm the one who create the SSAS project. I did add the date column and the power bi shows the day of the week on the x-axis, but the way it counts the value is based on the days, not the date. 

Thanks for your suggestion tho, really appreciate it.

Comment: You can sort by another column in the SSAS Tabular Designer. Click the column and have a look at the properties/options